# GitHub Action Error : Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: github, github-actions

[image]

### Workflow file for this run

##### .github/workflows/profile-3d.yml

```
name: GitHub-Profile-3D-Contrib

on:
  schedule: # 03:00 JST == 18:00 UTC
    - cron: "0 0/3 * * *"
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: generate-github-profile-3d-contrib
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: yoshi389111/github-profile-3d-contrib@0.7.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          USERNAME: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
      - name: Commit & Push
        run: |
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add -A .
          git commit -m "generated"
          git push
```

Got Error when I create a *yml* of the file.

#### Error Like this -

Run git config user.name github-actions
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

### Just Wanna to add this kind of graph in my profile README file

https://github.com/yoshi389111/github-profile-3d-contrib